# SQL Server Authentication Vs Windows Authentication - asp.net core Web API - 500 error - IIS 7.5

Tags: sql-server-2012, iis-7.5, asp.net-core-webapi

I have very weird issue while deploying asp.net core web api application to IIS 7.5.

If I am using SQL Server authentication mode for SQL Server 2012, and set below connection string in `appsettings.json` file, then there is no error while accessing web api,

**success**

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
           "SchedulerConnection": "Server=ABC\\SQL2012;Database=SchedulerDb;user id=sa;password=XYZ;"
    }
}
```

But while I am using windows authentication mode for SQL Server 2012, then after hosting asp.net core web api to IIS, I am getting "500" Internal Server Error.

**Fail**

```
{
   "ConnectionStrings": {
        "SchedulerConnection": "Server=ABC\\SQL2012;Database=SchedulerDb;persist security info=True;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
   }
}
```

What setting I need to make to run web api using SQL Server Windows authentication??